# App Engine throws 404 Not Found for any path but root

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I want to split my App Engine implementation into several files. So I wrote in my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:

- url: /imageuploader
  script: imageuploader.app

- url: /search
  script: main.app

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

libraries:
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

Basically I search and image upload to be on different paths and root path to have index file.

Here are my handlers:

main.py:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        #Implementation

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

imageuploader.py:

```
class UserPhoto(ndb.Model):
    blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()


class PhotoUploadFormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # [START upload_url]
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo')
        # [END upload_url]
        # [START upload_form]
        # To upload files to the blobstore, the request method must be "POST"
        # and enctype must be set to "multipart/form-data".
        self.response.out.write("""
<html><body>
<form action="{0}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body></html>""".format(upload_url))
        # [END upload_form]


# [START upload_handler]
class PhotoUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
            user_photo = UserPhoto(
                user=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                blob_key=upload.key())
            user_photo.put()

            self.redirect('/view_photo/%s' % upload.key())

        except:
            self.error(500)
# [END upload_handler]


# [START download_handler]
class ViewPhotoHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, photo_key):
        if not blobstore.get(photo_key):
            self.error(404)
        else:
            self.send_blob(photo_key)
# [END download_handler]


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', PhotoUploadFormHandler),
    ('/upload_photo', PhotoUploadHandler),
    ('/view_photo/([^/]+)?', ViewPhotoHandler),
], debug=True)
# [END all]
```

Now, the weird thing is that if I set

```
-url: /.*
    script: main.app
```

It all works. I also tried `/search/.+` and `/imageuploader/.+`. I must have forgotten something completely obvious but I cant figure out what is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `app.yaml` route script config (like `script: imageuploader.app`) requires a python file with a matching name (`imageuploader.py` in this case) which is defining an app called `app` (just like the `main.py` does) with app routes being, of course, a subset of (or equal to) the corresponding path from the `app.yaml` file (`/imageuploader` in this case).

So, problems with your implementation:

- the `main.py` app path is `/` - doesn't match the corresponding `/search` path in `app.yaml`
- none of the 3 app path patterns in `imageuploader.py` matches the corresponding `/imageuploader` path in `app.yaml`
- the `/` path in `app.yaml` is actually mapped to the static resource `index.html`, so it'll be served by GAE directly - no point adding a handler for it as that handler should never be invoked (you may want to revisit the static resources mapping).

Your attempt using `/.*` mapped to `main.app` could only have worked **before** you removed the handler code now in `imageuploader.py`, but should not be working with the `main.py` content from your question.

Assuming your patterns in the `app.yaml` are the ones you desire, these would be the app configs you'd need (to continue with your approach):

main.py:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/search', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

imageuploader.py:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/imageuploader', ...),  # TODO: revisit mappings
], debug=True)
```

But I'd suggest a simpler to manage approach, using [webapp2's lazy loading](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#guide-routing-lazy-handlers) of the handler code.

You keep a single, generic mapping in the `app.yaml`, which would match **any url pattern** in the `main.py` file:

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

You have a single app route mapping definition in `main.py`, but which can lazy-load handlers from both `main.py` as well as other modules/files. For example something like this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([    
    ('/upload', 'imageuploader.PhotoUploadFormHandler'),
    ('/upload_photo', 'imageuploader.PhotoUploadHandler'),
    ('/view_photo/([^/]+)?', 'imageuploader.ViewPhotoHandler'),
    ('/main_page', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

A middle-ground approach is also possible, allowing you to completely de-couple `imageuploader.py` from `main.py` but with a slightly more careful url pattern choice.

You could have in `app.yaml`:

```
- url: /photo.*
  script: imageuploader.app
```

And in `imageuploader.py` have url patterns matching that `/photo.*` one:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/photo_upload_form', PhotoUploadFormHandler),
    ('/photo_upload', PhotoUploadHandler),
    ('/photo_view/([^/]+)?', ViewPhotoHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Do I need a reference to imageuploader.py in main.py?

Comment: In the last example yes - that's how you indicate where (i.e. which module) is that lazy handler loaded from. Similar, if you want, to `from imageuploader import PhotoUploadFormHandler` (which you can use as well, except it'll be loaded right away, when th einstance starts, not lazy-loaded when the actual request for it comes in).