# How to use Python main() function in GAE (Google App Engine)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, program-entry-point, wsgi

I'd like to use a `main()` function in my GAE code 
(note: the code below is just a minimal demonstration for a much larger program, hence the need for a `main()`).

If I use the following code, it performs as expected:

```
import webapp2

class GetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in GET')

class SetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in SET')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/get',    GetHandler),
    ('/set',    SetHandler),
], debug=True)
```

where my `app.yaml` is:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

**However**, I cannot figure out how to implement a `main()` function, and still have `app` act as it does in the code at the top. Namely, the following:

```
# with main()
import webapp2

class GetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in GET')

class SetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in SET')

def main():
    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/get',    GetHandler),
        ('/set',    SetHandler),
    ], debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

gives the following error for `http://localhost:8080/get:`

```
$ dev_appserver.py .
INFO     2016-10-17 11:29:30,962 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-10-17 11:29:31,059 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:45865
INFO     2016-10-17 11:29:31,069 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-10-17 11:29:31,073 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2016-10-17 11:29:37,461 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/.../sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 302, in _LoadHandler
    raise err
ImportError: <module 'main' from '/home/.../main.pyc'> has no attribute app
INFO     2016-10-17 11:29:37,496 module.py:788] default: "GET /get HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

### Edit 1

Trying:

```
# with main()
import webapp2

app = webapp2.RequestHandler()

class GetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in GET')

class SetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in SET')

def main():
    global app
    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/get',    GetHandler),
        ('/set',    SetHandler),
    ], debug=True)
    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = main()
```

Results in:

```
INFO     2016-10-17 12:30:34,751 module.py:402] [default] Detected file changes:
  /home/openstack/googleAppEngine/fastsimon/task2/task2_with_main/main.py
ERROR    2016-10-17 12:30:42,328 wsgi.py:279] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/openstack/googleAppEngine/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
TypeError: 'RequestHandler' object is not callable
INFO     2016-10-17 12:30:42,335 module.py:788] default: "GET /get HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the point?

Comment: As I mentioned (1st para), I have many handlers that need to be implemented, and it's much more orderly in my app to keep them in a separate function. Is my request to utilise a `main()` in GAE an impossibility, @Daniel?

Comment: This article explains why: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe

Comment: @boardrideryou can implement your app across function and files, I still don't understand why you want to use `main()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the solution was quite simple (it kept eluding me because it hid in plain sight): `__name__` is **main** and not **__main__**!

In short, the following code utilises a `main()` as expected:

```
# with main()
import webapp2

class GetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in GET')

class SetHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('in SET')

def main():
    global app
    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/get',    GetHandler),
        ('/set',    SetHandler),
    ], debug=True)

# Note that it's 'main' and not '__main__'
if __name__ == 'main':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

GAE apps are not designed to be standalone apps, a `main()` function doesn't make a lot of sense for them.

Basically GAE apps are really just collections of handler code and rules/configurations designed to extend and customize the behaviour of the generic GAE infra/sandbox code so that it behaves your app. You can see that from your backtrace - other code is invoking your handler code (and the stack before reaching your code can be *a lot deeper* than that).

In your particular case the `app` variable **must** be a global in `main.py` to match the `script: main.app` config line in the `app.yaml` config file. This is what the traceback is about.

As for organizing the code for huge apps, there are other ways of doing it:

- splitting the app in multiple [modules/services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/an-overview-of-app-engine#services_the_building_blocks_of_app_engine), each with their own `app.yaml` config file. For example: [Can a default service/module in a Google App Engine app be a sibling of a non-default one in terms of folder structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo)
- splitting a service/module into multiple "scripts" - primary entry points into the `app.yaml` file similar to your `main.py` file, each with their own `app` config` - which really are just mappers between routes and handlers. For example: [App Engine throws 404 Not Found for any path but root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349590/app-engine-throws-404-not-found-for-any-path-but-root)
- splitting the handlers for one `app` mapper into multiple files, using webapp2's lazy loaded handler technique. Examples:

  - [App Engine: Few big scripts or many small ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453441/app-engine-few-big-scripts-or-many-small-ones/33457227#33457227)
  - [What determines start up time of dynamic instance and can it vary between weeks if code is same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635012/what-determines-start-up-time-of-dynamic-instance-and-can-it-vary-between-weeks/34637044#34637044)

In an extreme case a `main.py` file could contain *just* the `app` variable - that is really the only requirement.

Answer (score 0):

https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html describes how to use GAE apps outside of the GAE environment:

```
from myapp import app

def main():
    from paste import httpserver
    httpserver.serve(app, host='localhost', port='8070')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I did that in order to debug my app using the Pycharm IDE instead of from the dev_appserver command window; it works fine.  I compare results with dev_appserver running on port 8080 and the debugger running on 8070.