# Python - main.py getting big, need to package handlers

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

My main.py file is getting really big!

I'm aware you can move the Request handlers out to their own files in a package.

I've seen you need to add some **init**.py file to the handlers folder to declare this, and I expect you need to then import your handlers to main.py.

My questions is: what is the correct process for doing this? Any good documentation would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it at the python module (i.e. `.py` file) level as well, not necessarily at a package level, a bit simpler (no need for `__init__.py` files). Up to you.

For python module level split you can find some examples here:

- [App Engine throws 404 Not Found for any path but root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349590/app-engine-throws-404-not-found-for-any-path-but-root/39352009#39352009)
- [What determines start up time of dynamic instance and can it vary between weeks if code is same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635012/what-determines-start-up-time-of-dynamic-instance-and-can-it-vary-between-weeks/34637044#34637044)

Comment: So I can move each RequestHandler to its own requesthandler.py file? And then use app.yaml to call the appropriate file?

Comment: If you want to use `app.yaml` you need to do a bit more in those files, see the quote in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547973/deploy-python-script-on-google-cloud-platform/42548535#42548535

Comment: I prefer splitting inside `main.py` - seems simpler to me.